# what determines what bytes are output from std::endl

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, special-characters, iostream

I have a large code base that uses std::cout to generate its output, and it uses std::endl all over the place to generate its newlines. This program seems to generate only linefeeds for the endl, which isn't a huge problem in itself, but for whatever reason, wasn't what I had expected.

So as a reality check, I built a simple program to pump endl's into cout, compiled it with the same compiler and examined the output from that. *That* program emits both CR and LF for endl.

It doesn't look like the large program plays any games with cout to change the way endl works, at least not that I can recognize, so it seems strange that it should behave differently than the small program. It seems as though the large program must be doing something to change the defaults. What am I missing here?

Both programs were compiled using MinGW gcc 4.5.2 on 32bit windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to Tomalak Geret'kal's answer: the fact that `endl` expands to the platform-specific endline is a popular misconception.

Inside a C/C++ application the only "official" newline (at least, as far as streams and stream-related functions are concerned) is `'\n'`. The translation from `'\n'` to the platform-specific newline is done *inside the streams*<sup>1</sup> when they are opened in text mode (i.e. without the `ios::bin` flag).

`endl`, instead, is used to force a stream flush after the `'\n'`; this can be useful for console output, but (1) often this is not the case (`cout` is automatically flushed when input is requested from `cin` via the tied-stream mechanism) and only wastes CPU time, and (2) you often find it used also on file streams, where it is almost never useful, and results in poor file writing performance.

---

1. As discussed in the comments, as far as the standard is concerned the translation could actually happen at any level below the stream (e.g. the stream may translate the presence/absence of `ios::bin` into a flag for the underlying OS file management functions, and it would be responsibility of the OS to do the translation); in reality, mainstream OSes do not have particular flags for this kind of translation, mainly because their file APIs are content-agnostic (you tell them what to write, they write it without modifications).

Comment: Actually there's nothing in the standard about translating `\n` "inside the streams". I believe it's done at the interface between the stream and the file system, possibly by the OS itself.

Comment: @Tomalak: correct, the standard as usual leaves complete freedom to the implementations, but I don't think that the OS should bother with this kind of stuff, and actually neither `CreateFile` on Windows or `open` on POSIX have a special flag for "text mode", so in usually this will be done inside the stream (or inside the corresponding C stream if iostream is built on stdio).

Comment: OK, that makes sense. The standard doesn't really make it explicit that the _meaning_ of streaming things to a file stream is implementation-defined, whilst it doesn't pretend otherwise either. Seems like a bit of a hole, and line-ending conversion fell right through it!

Comment: @Tomalak: still, just to be safe, I clarified my answer. :)

Comment: The language standard can't reasonably required a specific way for the OS to store a text file. Some OSs do care and some, like IBM zOS, store text lines as variable length records with a stored record length and no separators.

Comment: @Bo: I don't think anybody's suggesting that the current scenario is unreasonable!

Answer (score 4):

`std::endl` is defined by the C++ Standard to perform the following:

- Stream a `'\n'` character;
- Stream the `std::flush` I/O manipulator.

If you're seeing carriage returns at the other end of the stream, then that's occurring at the file interface (and not in the stream functionality itself); in particular, on Windows, you can expect `"\n"` to be translated transparently to `"\r\n"` during *text-mode* output to files.

So, check that your files are both being opened in text- or binary- mode respectively. There is nothing else in C++ that could affect this behaviour.

[This FAQ entry](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.12) pretty much covers what I just said, too.

Comment: **Note:** I have decided that "at the file interface" shall mean "in the part of the `fstream` implementation that is not standard-governed"... which is pretty much all of it.

Answer (score 1):

When a file is opened in "TEXT" Mode (the default when you create file streams).

The '\n' character is converted into a platform specific "end of line sequence" when you write it to a file. Conversely the "end of line sequence" is converted into a '\n' when you read from the file.

Note if you open a file in "BINARY" Mode this conversion does not happen.

In relation to std::endl

```
stream << std::endl
```

Is equivalent to:

```
stream << '\n' << std::flush;
```

Thus if your stream is a std::fstream (that was opened normally) then '\n' character will be converted into "end of line sequence" which on some platforms is '\r\n'